# Library overrides - Issue with armatures when re-opening file

Tags: library-overrides

I am working on a project with many characters - each linked from one single .blend file, using library overrides.

[image]
The outliner in the image below shows the source file for the characters.
[image]
I really like the library override system - everything is working perfectly and exactly as intended - until I open the exact same file on a different system, save and re-open.

This is what happens:
[image]

All the characters 'merge' into one armature.
The image below shows that the library override icons are still present.

[image]

I have checked that paths are set to relative on both systems, and each system is using the exact same Blender version 3.0.0

Why this is happening is just beyond me, hence this request for help. Has anyone experienced this and figured out a solution before?

Edit:
When appending from this file, here is the list of errors that is posted: (taken with a camera)
[image]

Comment: Hi thankyou for your reply :) yes indeed they are the same version, and I should have included that in my question. I shall fix that now!

Comment: They do, question updated! No need to apologize :)

Comment: Hehe we'll get to the bottom of it :) Did you Duplicate Linked your collections when adding a new character or create a new lib override from the original linked collection each time ? Or if you prefer, do you armatures, bones or meshes objects share the same data ? You can see if a mesh is shared in the mesh properties for instance : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdyKe.png

Comment: Each character was added using file->link [collection] and then 'make library override'. The part I find most bizzare is everything works as intended, even on a different system - until after saving and re-opening.

Comment: Hmm it's beginning to look like a system limitation unfortunately... :/

Comment: The system that works perfectly is an old pc whereas the one that has the issue with REopening after saving anything has a Ryzen9 and an AMD6700. /shrug I appreciate you taking the time to reply to the question :)

Comment: Yeah I meant a Blender bug, not a machine problem ^^ Sorry can't help you more than that, I'll stop hijacking the comment section. Good luck !

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reproduce this problem with just two characters?  If so could you then reopen, but save to a different file?  Does the problem still exist? If so could you add these two files to your question, both from the second system: A) The file that you open and the characters are good. B) The file that you save from that file but the characters are merged? (([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Hi Marty thankyou kindly for your reply. So far I am trying to reproduce the problem with 2 characters but it just keeps on working perfectly doh! I have not given up yet, and hopefully further attempts will either reproduce, or identify the problem. I will keep you posted with the results.

Comment: Update: I have not yet been able to reproduce the problem with a new project - it only seems to occur within this project. The problem can be re-produced on the same computer system by appending from this problematic file. If I append the scene with the characters, it gives a list of errors about corrupted datablocks. I have updated the question to include this image, though it had to be taken with a camera to capture.

Comment: Update: It has now started happening to the original file. I am going to abandon this project until library overrides are ready, which they are clearly not at this stage. Otherwise every 1 hour of work I put in ends up invoking 3 hours of back-tracking, fixing unexpected behavior.

Comment: you might fill in a bug report, be as detailed as possible.
this way you help blenders development.

Comment: Update: since the version update the problem has gone away, but now blender crashes about 1 every 2 minutes while working on this project.

Answer (score 0):

Since the latest update, this issue seems to have been solved.